# Twitter app that creates reading lists?

Tags: android, mobile, twitter

I like to put people into different lists in twitter, but the the official twitter app doesn't really support reading lists.

Is there a third-party twitter app that nicely organizes each list and notify you when they have new content, similar to how RSS readers might work?

os: Android KitKat

Comment: You might wish to scroll through my list of [Twitter Clients](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_twitter). Take a closer look at e.g. [TweetCaster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handmark.tweetcaster) and [Plume](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levelup.touiteur) which both support lists. I'm using the latter, but have not (yet) worked with lists – so I cannot tell you how close that comes to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Some RSS readers can import your twitter feed, which allows you to then organize them in folders. I use [**InoReader**](https://www.inoreader.com). You can give it permission to your Twitter account under `Preferences -> Integration -> Twitter`

[image]

After that, you can create subfolders or tags and import your feeds by copying the links of the accounts you're following

[image]

[InoReader has an Android app that runs on Android 2.3 and up](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.innologica.inoreader)